# getting 404 on system configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, system.xml, 404-page, system-configuration

I am using Magento 1 to create a system configuration left menu is created successfully but when I click on that getting 404.
**what I have tried**

1. Re-logging into the dashboard.
2. Using ACL.
3. Clearing **`var/session/*`** and **`var/cache/*`**

> Code(system.xml):

[image]

> Code(adminhtml.xml):

[image]

Comment: Add code, not screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you should replace each occurence of `module='Ranosys_CancelPendingOrder'` with `module='the_alias_of_your_helper'`. The alias is defined in your config.xml ine the helper section.

Then you should replace `Ranosys` with `ranosys` in your adminhtml file. (because the section is called `ranosys` in your system.xml file.

After changes, you have to clear cache and lougout/login.

Comment: done thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

try to Change module="CancelPendingOrder"

Try to add below code in after  `adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
            ........
```

Comment: thanks for your response but Mage_CancelPendingOrder_Helper_Data error on the changeing module name